# Рандомная загрузка Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

Пожалуйста подскажите как в Bootstrap Carousel при загрузке страницы каждый раз начинать с рандомного слайда? Пожалуйста подскажите[

Comment: если это поможет я буду рад - https://www.sitepoint.com/full-screen-bootstrap-carousel-random-initial-image/ (en) И работающий пример -http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/pjJGQE

Comment: @diproart Спасибо огромное!!!